# Erro em filtro de listagem com php e jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estava tentando fazer um filtro de listagem, gostaria que a cada hora que o select mudasse de valor atualizasse minha tabela, mas está ocorrendo um erro que não consigo encontrar, ao iniciar a página ou alterar o select não é retornado nenhum valor na minha tabela e é exibido a alert de erro.

> Index.html

```
<select id="filtro">
  <option> Alunos </option>
  <option> Professores </option>
 </select> 

 <br> <br>

 <table border="1"> 
    <tr align="center">
       <td> Nome </td>
       <td> Email </td>
       <td> Telefone </td>
       <td> RG </td>
       <td> CPF </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="nome"> </td>
       <td id="email"> </td>
       <td id="tel"> </td>
       <td id="rg"> </td>
       <td id="cpf"> </td>
    </tr>
 </table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {

     filtro();

     $('#filtro').change(() => {
        filtro();   
     });   

  });

  function filtro(){

    var data = {
       acao: "filtro",
       filtro: $('#filtro').val(),
    };

    console.log(data);

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "listagem.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        sucess: (data) => {

           data = JSON.parse(data);

           $('#nome').html(data.nome);
           $('#email').html(data.email);
           $('#tel').html(data.tel);
           $('#rg').html(data.rg);
           $('#cpf').html(data.cpf);

        }, error: () => {
           alert('Ocorreu algum erro.');    
        }    
     });

  }
</script>
```

> listagem.php

```
include('conexao.php');

$data = $_POST ? $_POST : $_GET;

$response = [
  'error' => ''
];

if(!$data){
   $response['error'] = 'Nada na requisição';
}

if($data['acao'] == 'filtro'){

   $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE nivel={$data['filtro']}";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $response = $row;    
   }

}

return json_encode($response);
```

Comment: *"é exibido a alert de erro."* certo, e já tentou ver qual o erro, inspecionar a mensagem pra tentar perceber o problema?  use `}, error: (request, status, error) => {` e veja o que tem nas variáveis que o ajax devolve

Comment: o erro retornado é esse: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0, você sabe me dizer oque pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

O erro *SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0* ocorre pois está tentando parsear para JSON algo que já está no formato JSON, devido ao `dataType: "json"` setado no objeto da requisição e ao uso do `json_encode()` no lado do backend.
Algo que pode estar causando problemas também é seu arquivo **listagem.php**, uma vez que está usando `return` em `return json_encode($response);` fora do escopo de uma função (`function`). **Mude** no objeto de requisição ajax a palavra `sucess` para `success`, **remova** `data = JSON.parse(data);` e tente assim no lado do PHP:

```
<?php

include('conexao.php');

$data = $_POST ? $_POST : $_GET;

$response = [
  'error' => ''
];

if(!$data){
  $response['error'] = 'Nada na requisição';
}

if($data['acao'] == 'filtro' && isset($data['filtro'])){

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `nivel` = '{$data['filtro']}'";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $response = $row;    
  }

}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Espero ter ajudado.